# How can I find videos of mathematics at graduate level, especially on linear algebraic groups

Tags: education, learning, online-resources

I am studying mathematics by myself, and I find it very helpful to watch online course videos.

There are many such videos on undergraduate courses, such as elementary calculus, abstract algebra, general topology and so on. But, it is difficult for me to find videos at graduate level. I find [this](http://lecturefox.com/math/?page=1), but most of the courses provide only notes.

So, would you please share some links of videos of mathematical courses at graduate level? Or of videos that are enlightening to a mathematical student at this level? **Especially on Linear Algebraic Groups, Algebraic Geometry and related topics**.

Thanks for answering. Also, many thanks to the colleges and teachers providing these videos, which are really very precious for studying math.

Comment: At first I have to offer a "Wow" because you study math on your own. This was the way I came to math, too, but it's sometimes getting really hard. I don't any videos since I was better at learning from books, but if sometime you want to read some really interesting stuff e.g. on algebraic differential topology, then contact me, I can name you several good books on that.

Comment: @David Heider: Thank you very much for your kindness. It is really very hard sometimes. But math is something I love, and I am not afraid of any difficulty. Also, if I pass the coming test, I will become a math student next year. I have no other way to contact you than (at)ing you here, but I'd be very happy to hear your advice on the studying materials. Thanks again :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[Here](http://www.ictp.tv/diploma/search07-08.php?activityid=MTH&course=Algebraic_Geometry) is a link to about 40 hours of lectures given in 2007/08 by [L. Goettsche](http://users.ictp.it/~gottsche/) on Algebraic Geometry as part of the Postgraduate Diploma program at the [Abdus Salam International Centre for Theoretical Physics](http://www.ictp.it/) in Trieste, Italy.

Comment: It would be good if you could please add some context to this response. If the link breaks in the future, this answer becomes essentially useless. I would suggest providing a proper citation for the video (along with the link), so there is some chance of it being tracked down if your link fails.

Comment: I have edited your answer to provide some basic citation information. I hope you don't mind.

Comment: @cardinal: It's OK, thanks.

Comment: This is very good for learning Algebraic Geometry. Thanks to both of you :)

Answer (score 0):

http://www.mathtube.org/ is very good. There are also videos on the fields institute webpage http://www.fields.utoronto.ca/video-archive

In solidarity

Answer (score -2):

There are many at DNAtube, such as: http://www.dnatube.com/video/6899/A-Par ... DE-Formula , and many others from this author. And more on YouTube, such as at: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4JFFLruvqP4 by the same author. But Algebraic Groups & Geometry in particular not sure.

Comment: Differential equations is rather quite far from algebraic geometry. The links don't appear to be what the OP is looking for.